# PostgreSQL and matching row on multiple

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm making a car statistic solution where I need to charge per kilometer driven.

I have the following table:

```
table: cars
columns: car_id, km_driven

table: pricing
columns: from, to, price
```

Content in my `cars` table can be:

```
car_id, km_driven
2, 430
3, 112
4, 90
```

Content on my `pricing` table can be:

```
from, to, price
0, 100, 2
101, 200, 1
201, null, 0.5
```

Meaning that the first 100 km cost 2USD per km, the next 100 km cost 1USD per km and everything above costs 0.5USD per km.

Is there a logic and simple way to calculate cost for my `cars` via `PostgreSQL`?

So if a `car` has driven ex. 201, then the price would be `100x2 + 100x1 + 0.5`, not simply `201x0.5`.

Comment: what is "this" ? Do you mean the total price for the km driven ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. My mistake.

Comment: No, there is no simple way to do this. Per cars entry you must loop through the pricing table and step by step apply the pricing for the kilometers. The best tool for this would be a programming language. I suppose this can be done with PL/pgSQL. Otherwise you could write an app in whatever other language. In SQL you'd use a recursive query for this.

Comment: 1) avoid using `from`  and  `to` as identifiers, it are reserved words. 2) for calculations it is more convenient to use *half open* intervals, e.g.`{100,200}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write the query as:

```
select c.car_id, c.km_driven, 
   sum(( least(p.to_km, c.km_driven) - p.from_km + 1) * p.price) as dist_price
from cars c join
     pricing p
     on c.km_driven >= p.from_km
group by c.car_id, c.km_driven;
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c78332f233ba73ced24d0738c614523d).

Comment: Shouldn't `p.from_km + 1` simply be `p.from_km` for more accurate result? Otherwise 1 extra km would be added to the wrong range.

Comment: @AlfredBalle . . . The results look correct to me in the db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Modified from @sean-johnston's answer:

```
select 
  car_id, km_driven, 
  sum(case 
    when km_driven>=start then (least(finish,km_driven)-start+1)*price 
    else 0
  end) as dist_price
from cars,pricing
group by car_id,km_driven
```

- Original ranges kept
- *where km_driven >= start* omitted (its optional but might improve performance)

fiddling a bit more, case can be omitted when where is in place

```
select 
  car_id, km_driven, 
  sum((least(finish,km_driven)-start+1)*price) as dist_price
from cars,pricing
where km_driven >= start
group by car_id,km_driven
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=338c63d288509499b7061317409fcb2d)

Comment: Shouldn't `start+1` simply be `start` ? Seems to provide a more accurate result?

Answer (score 1):

I would *definitely* do this using a procedure, as it can be implemented in a very straightforward manner using loops. However, you should be able to do something similar to this:

```
select car_id, sum(segment_price)
from (
  select 
  car_id, 
  km_driven, 
  f, 
  t, 
  price, 
  driven_in_segment, 
  segment_price
  from (
      select 
      car_id, 
      km_driven, 
      f, 
      t, 
      price, 
      (coalesce(least(t, km_driven), km_driven) - f) driven_in_segment, 
      price * (coalesce(least(t, km_driven), km_driven) - f) segment_price
      from 
      -- NOTE: cartesian product here
      cars, 
      pricing
      where f < km_driven
  )
) data
group by car_id
order by car_id
```

I find that pretty less readable, though.

**UPDATE:**

That query is a bit more complex than necessary, I was trying out some things with window functions that were not needed in the end. A simplified version here that should be equivalent:

```
select car_id, sum(segment_price)
from (
  select 
  car_id, 
  km_driven, 
  f, 
  t, 
  price, 
  (coalesce(least(t, km_driven), km_driven) - f) driven_in_segment, 
  price * (coalesce(least(t, km_driven), km_driven) - f) segment_price
  from 
  -- NOTE: cartesian product here
  cars, 
  pricing
  where f < km_driven
) data
group by car_id
order by car_id
```

Comment: Seems to work perfect. Do you think a procedure with loops would perfome better, or simply more readable?

Comment: More readable in my opinion, probably slightly worse performance.

Answer (score 1):

Judicious use of case/sum combinations. However, firstly need to make your ranges consistent. I'll choose to change the first range to 1,100. Given that then the following should give you want you're after. (I've also used start/finish as from/to are reserved words).

```
select
  car_id, km_driven,
  sum (case
    when finish is null and km_driven >= start
      then (km_driven-start+1) * price
    when km_driven >= start
      then (case
              when (km_driven - start + 1) > finish
                then (finish - start + 1)
              else (km_driven - start + 1)
              end) * price
    else 0
    end) as dist_price
from cars, pricing
where km_driven >= start
group by 1, 2;
```

Explanation:

1. We join against any range where the journey is at least as far as the start of the range.
2. The open ended range is handled in the first case clause and is fairly simple.
3. We need an inner case clause for the closed ranges as we only want the part of the journey in that range.
4. Then sum the results of that for the total journey price.

If you don't want to (or can't) make your ranges consistent then you'd need to add a third outer case for the start range.

Answer (score 0):

you can use join and calculate your cost by using case when

```
    select c.car_id, case when p.price=.5 
   then  100*2+100*1+(c.km_driven-200)*0.5 
    when   p.price=1 then 100*2+(c.km_driven-100)*1
    else c.km_driven*p.price as cost
   from cars c join pricing p
   on c.km_driven>=p.from and c.km_driven<=p.to
```

Comment: Think this wouldn't take into account that the first 100 km always costs 2USD, the next 100 costs 1USD. So if a `car` has driven ex. 201, then the price would be `100x2 + 100x1 + 0.5`, not simply `201x0.5`.

Comment: @AlfredBalle put this example on question please